# PIR Sensor triggering voltage not enough

Tags: arduino, pir

I'm using a HC-SR501 PIR sensor.
The sensor is working fine, it outputs 3.3 V on motion detection.
But when I connect the PIR sensor to pin 2 (interrupt) of an Arduino pro mini,
the voltage output is only 0.289 V on motion detection.
The sensor is detecting motion, it's just not giving enough voltage.
How is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sensor is putting out 0 to 3.3 V when open circuit, and 0 to 290 mV when connected to a microcontroller, then the micro is obviously loading the signal.

A normal CMOS input wouldn't load a signal like that, so obviously that input of the micro is not acting like a normal CMOS input.  Possible reasons include:

The pin is not configured as a input in firmware.  Check your code.

The pin is dedicated to some other function.  Check the datasheet.

Something else is loading the pin.  Check the schematic and your wiring.